# How to workaround Rust's borrow check of HashMap?

Tags: hashmap, rust, match

I have this code where `pat_vec` and `str_vec` are two iterators:

```
let mut pat_mapping: HashMap<char, &str> = HashMap::new();

for combi in pat_vec.zip(str_vec) {
    let (c, word) = combi;

    match pat_mapping.get(&c) {
        Some(phrase) => {
            if phrase.to_string() != word.to_string() {
                return false;
            }
        }

        None => {
            pat_mapping.insert(c, word);
        }
    }
}
```

This does not work, and the compiler complains that:

```
cannot borrow `pat_mapping` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable [E0502]
```

I understand that it might because `pat_mapping.get(&c)` borrowed `&self` as immutable, while the `insert()` method falls into the same scope but needs to borrow `&self` as mutable.

I have a work around:

```
match word_mapping.get(&c) {
    Some(phrase) => {
        if phrase.to_string() != word.to_string() {
            return false;
        }
    }
    None => {

        pat_trigger = true;
    }

};

if pat_trigger {
    pat_mapping.insert(c, word);
}
```

But introducing a boolean flag is redundant. Is there a way to work around the borrow check so as to do the match and insert in the same code block?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use [`entry`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html#method.entry):

```
match pat_mapping.entry(c) {
    Occupied(phrase) => {
        if phrase.get().to_string() != word.to_string() {
            return false;
        }
    },
    Vacant(vacant) => {
        vacant.insert(word);
    }
}
```

It also has the advantage of looking up the key only once.